# Nedb Find one item and change another

Tags: node.js, nedb

I am finding a piece of data by searching for the name, however, that person also has a score count, how could I just get the score count.

```
database.find({ username: username }, function(err, doc) {
    const data = doc
    console.log(data)

    if(data.length < 1 || data == undefined) {

    const scorecount = 1;
    database.insert({ username, scorecount})

    } else {
        console.log(data)
        //Here is where I want to be able to just get the score count and be able to change it
    }
})
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used NeDB; but in general what you need to do is map between the element you receive in `doc` and the argument that `database.insert()` expects. From reading the documentation I think you can just modify `doc` and pass it right back in:

```js
data.forEach((row) => {
  row.scorecount = (row.scorecount || 0) + 1
  database.insert(row)
})
```

Side note: `if (data.length < 1 || data == undefined)`. If `data` is in fact undefined then `data.length` will throw an error. Check `data == undefined` first. Or better yet, `!data` will catch any value which is falsy.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this